# Nodemailer cant find txt file

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, vercel

I've been looking for an answer on here for this but so far nothings worked.
Basically I've got a txt file and I want to send it using Nodemailer, thats it.
But I keep getting this error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data.txt'
The file exists and in the same directly as the .js file tasked with sending it so the paths correct.
I've checked my .json file and all packages I should need are present.
This all works locally so I'm seriously struggling to understand whats wrong.

Heres the code:

```
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'outlook',
auth:{
    user: 'myEmail',
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
}
});

data.map(coin => {
    if(coin.symbol !== 'BNB'){
        top80.push(coin.symbol.toUpperCase());
        cleanedOrders[coin.symbol.toUpperCase()] = [];
        }
    })

        let mailoptions = {
            from: 'senderEmail',
            to: 'toEmail',
            subject: 'Report',
            text: 'Find this months report attached.',
            attachments: [
                {
                    filename: 'report.txt',
                    path: 'data.txt'
                }
            ]
        }
        function getCoinData(numberOfCoins) {
            //should be < -1
            if (numberOfCoins > -1) {
                //console.log('All coin orders captured');
                //email results
                transporter.sendMail(mailoptions, (err, info) => {
                       if(err){
                           console.log(err);
                           res.json(`error compiling report: ${err}`);
                       } else {
                        res.json(`Report sent.`);
                       }
                   });
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you provide a relative path, the `nodemailer` will build up a path `relative` to `process.cwd` . The `process.cwd()` is the programs working dir or think of the location of your `main.js` file, the folder you start the program in!.

Say you have following folder structure:

```
main.js
-email
--email.js
--data.txt
```

If you start the program using `main.js` the `process.cwd()` argument will always be the folder the `main.js` is in even if the file `email.js` is called.

### Option 1

- Move `data.txt` to the root folder (same folder as `main.js` is in.)  and it will find it.

#### Option 2

- Provide an absolute path to `nodemailer`, best todo with global `__dirname`

```
var { join } = requiure('path')
let mailoptions = {
  from: 'senderEmail',
  to: 'toEmail',
  subject: 'Report',
  text: 'Find this months report attached.',
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: 'report.txt',
      
      // __dirname is equal to the directory the file is located in!.
      path: join(__dirname, 'data.txt')
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cheers Silvan, I used a combo of these 2 and it works perfectly. The __dirname was the clincher.